# Submit form or click submit input not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am currently working with `phantomjs 2.1.1` and `casper 1.1.0-beta5` to automate a basic login procedure. However, I am not having the best luck. Below I am able to succesfully fill in the the form with values but the issue arises when I try to submit it. I have tried using `click`, `selectors`, etc for submitting the form but no results. Any ideas of how to succesfully login with the below code?

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'error',
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1280,
        height: 720
    },
    pageSettings: {
        ignoreSslErrors: true,
        loadImages: false, // do not load images
        loadPlugins: false, // do not load NPAPI plugins (Flash, Silverlight, ...)
        webSecurityEnabled: false
    }
});

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
var fs = require('fs');
var cookies = JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);
fs.write("cookies.txt", cookies, 644);

casper.start('https://www.quora.com/login', function() {
    this.sendKeys("input[name=email]", "xxxxxxx@gmail.com", {
        keepFocus: true
    });
    this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.Tab);
    this.sendKeys("input[name=password]", "xxxxxxx", {
        keepFocus: true
    });
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById('__w2_IXl7ObX_login_form').submit();
    });
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('test.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Screenshot

[image]

HTML

```
<form id="__w2_gptxdFS_login_form" class="inline_login_form" method="POST">
    <div class="title">Login</div>
    <div class="form_inputs">
        <div class="form_column">
            <input id="__w2_gptxdFS_email" class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" type="text" w2cid="gptxdFS" tabindex="1" name="email" placeholder="Email" group="__w2_gptxdFS_interaction">
        </div>
        <div class="form_column">
            <input id="__w2_gptxdFS_password" class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" type="password" w2cid="gptxdFS" tabindex="2" name="password" placeholder="Password" group="__w2_gptxdFS_interaction">
        </div>
        <input id="__w2_gptxdFS_submit_button" class="submit_button ignore_interaction submit_button_disabled" type="submit" w2cid="gptxdFS" tabindex="4" value="Login" group="__w2_gptxdFS_interaction">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the form has any submit button in that?

Comment: @jobinsjohn the form has a submit input field with the label `login`

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of how the page looks like and the html code for the form? I have given a solution but that needs a button to be present, which I presume is the case mostly. You'll have a username field, a password field and one button that says sign in or login.

Comment: @prabugp I have added a screenshot and the html.

Comment: In my answer, I am clicking a button using `this.click('button[name="login"]'); ` But you can click on any selector as long it's clickable in the page. Can you try clicking `__w2_gptxdFS_submit_button`?

Comment: @prabugp That doesnt work either. It looks like the input `id` changes each time. I have also tried `this.clickLabel("Login");` and no luck.

Comment: You can use Xpath selectors which you can copy from Chrome's dev console. Alternatively, you can use `casper.thenEvaluate` to get the DOM element (dom.findElementsByClassName) and then do DOM manipulation (including firing the click event).

Comment: @MaryCoding fixed my answer. the attached code should let you login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should fix the issue for you:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    viewportSize: {
            width: 1280,
        height: 720
    },
    pageSettings: {
        ignoreSslErrors: true,
        loadImages: false, // do not load images
        loadPlugins: false, // do not load NPAPI plugins (Flash, Silverlight, ...)
        webSecurityEnabled: false,
        localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: false
    }
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo('Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR');
});

casper.start('https://www.quora.com', function() {
    this.echo ('loggin in');
    this.fillSelectors('div.form_inputs', {
        'input[type="text"]': 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
        'input[type="password"]': 'xxxxxxx'
    }, false);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.click('input.submit_button.ignore_interaction');
}).wait(5000, function(){});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('test.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I ran this with `casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any test.js` 
Otherwise, I was seeing `[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 500): https://www.quora.com/` when running the script in debug mode.

The screenshot after the above code is run is:

[image: Error message after clicking login]

The message 'no account found for this email' happens after we login. So, the login click is actually working in this case.

In the code, I'm waiting for 5 seconds for the login call to complete, but you can wait for some html element in the page that happens after login.

Comment: Just someone who had to do convert all the screens in a SPA to a PPT. May I ask 'why so curious'?

Comment: Ah. 'We' as in our team which is in no way related to the OP.

Comment: This did work perfectly. According to stackoverflow I cant award the bounty till the time is up.

Comment: Cool. Will remind you for the bounty after a week. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Send `\n` (enter key) in your password  it should submit form immediatelly after filling it.

```
this.sendKeys("input[name=password]", "xxxxxxx\n", {
        keepFocus: true
    });
```